# Robots.txt Disallow Certain Folder Names

Tags: robots.txt

I want to disallow robots from crawling any folder, at any position in the url with the name: `this-folder`.

Examples to disallow:

```
http://mysite.com/this-folder/
http://mysite.com/houses/this-folder/
http://mysite.com/some-other/this-folder/
http://mysite.com/no-robots/this-folder/
```

This is my attempt:

```
Disallow: /.*this-folder/
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially globbing and regular expressions are not supported:

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

but apparently some search engines support this.

Comment: OK, that's what I needed to know. Thank you for the link, it seems my Google is broken.