# Exclude specific Folders from being crawled?

Tags: html, web-crawler, backend, robots.txt, google-search

I want to exclude my user folders from being crawled by a search spider.

The structure is as follows. User accounts are under

```
www.mydomain.com/username
```

The problem is that I cannot exclude "/" in the disallowed part of my robots.txt because there are also other folders like

```
 www.mydomain.com/legal
 www.mydomain.com/privacy
```

There are also items that a user can generate which should be crawlable. They are under

```
 www.mydomain.com/username/items/itemId
```

**How do I have to set up my robots txt for that scenario?**

Answer (score 1):

Check the following answered question, maybe it might solve yours:

[Robots.txt Disallow Certain Folder Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501661/robots-txt-disallow-certain-folder-names)

Hope this helps.

## EDIT

see the following answered question in order to exclude a folder but not its childs

[Robots.txt Allow sub folder but not the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609031/robots-txt-allow-sub-folder-but-not-the-parent)

and you also should consider using the structure as follows:

```
mydomain.com/users/user1/subfolder
mydomain.com/users/user2/subfolder
```

in order to target your rules more accurate.

Comment: Well it helps to solve the first problem but not the second. Because, the username is in the path to the items. Any idea on this issue?

Comment: username is a variable? lets say that you have 2 users (taxicala and confile) you will have 2 folders, right? (www.mydomain.com/taxicala/ and www.mydomain.com/confile/)

Comment: yes? and in these folders there are the subfolders /items/ i.e., confile/items/ and taxicala/items/. I want that everything in these subfolders should be crawlable. How can I do that?

Comment: see my EDIT in the answer.

Comment: is it also possible without the users folder?

Comment: Well, I suppose, but you should investigate how to write the robots.txt file dinamically, because when you add a user, you will have to add a rule to the file. If you have a users folder containing all users, you can exclude /users and whenever a user is added, it will match the rule and it will be excluded. The tricky part is to allow the subfolders of each user.

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, you should follow taxicala's suggestion to change your directory structure.

If you absolutely cannot change your directory structure, you could use the allow directive and wildcards to deal with both problems:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /legal$
Allow: /privacy$
Allow: /*/items/
Disallow: /
```

Just be aware that not all robots support this syntax. This will definitely work for all major search engines, but it may not work for some older robots. Also, this is not particularly future-proof. If you later add some new top-level pages and you forget to add them to the robots.txt file, they will be silently blocked. The ideal approach is to use a directory structure that isolates the things you want blocked from the things you don't.

Comment: What does the $ sign stands for?

Comment: The $ means "end of URL", so /legal$ will match /legal but it won't match /legal/subdir or /legalese or legal?param=value.